# Count number of units/nodes in LSTM network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a neural network, where some layers are LSTM nodes/units.

How do I count how many LSTM nodes/units are in a given model?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your research with us. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Hi @BABAKASHRAFI This is a very straight-forward question. I have tried plenty, searched a lot, but haven't found anything. If you see an obvious solution, please do tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(len([l for l in model.layers if isinstance(l, tf.keras.layers.LSTM)]))
```